# What is a discrete table?

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-model, pattern-recognition

I've been reading Bishop's book on pattern recognition and machine learning and I keep finding the term **discrete tables** (mostly in the hidden markov models chapter) but I can't seem to find any information about what those tables consist of. Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ctrl-f'd 'discrete table' and I found only one sentence with it.

> Indeed, the model is tractable for a wide range of emission distributions including
>   discrete tables, Gaussians, and mixtures of Gaussians.

It means that for any time $t$, the observational distribution $p(x_t|z_t)$ is just some custom finite distribution. There's no special name for this, so he just calls it a discrete table. Conditional on the state being some value $z_t$, $x_t$ can take on a finite number of values with corresponding probabilities, whatever you want them to be.

Comment: I think I saw it somewhere before that sentence but can't seem to find it. Thanks, I understand it now!